# What does axis-aligned mean?

Tags: wpf, bounding-box, rect

What does axis-aligned mean. For example when you get a bounding rectangle of a geometry it says:

> Gets a Rect that specifies the axis-aligned bounding box of the Geometry.

What does axis-aligned mean, and what axis is it aligned to, the containing panel/element parent or the window?

Comment: I'd guess it's talking about the x- and y-axes.  So you have a rectangle that isn't slanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the rectangle isn't rotated at all, its edges follow the X and Y axes.

Comment: Huh? If you rotate the Geometry object, you will get a slightly different sized / positioned box that is still axis-aligned.